# r cran: How to produce the actual values instead of the number of observations in the vector using & function?

Tags: r

The data in my csv looks like this for example:
variable 1, column 1: Embassy Name

```
Embassy_Name       
Argentina           
Argentina           
Belgium             
Bulgaria            
Switzerland         
Switzerland         
Switzerland
```

Variable 2, column 2: City name

```
City_name
Chicago    
Boston    
LA  
LA   
Boston   
LA      
Chicago
```

Now i need to find which countries have embassy's in all 3 cities like SWITZERLAND above for example so i wrote the code:

```
city2<-length(Embassy[Embassy$City== "Los Angeles" & Embassy$City== "Chicago" & Embassy$City== "Boston" ,])
```

All it returns is that there are 5 countries who have embassies in all 3.... but I need to know which countries I need R to give me a list of the text strings telling exactly which 5 countries that is?

DESIRED OUTPUT for example: a list of the countries where they have embassies in all 3 cities:
 Switzerland, India, France, Norway, Japan

The actual data is 156  obs:

```
structure(list(embassy = structure(c(" Afghanistan ", " Argentina ", 
" Argentina    ", " Australia ", " Australia ", " Austria ", 
" Austria ", " Azerbaijan ", " Bangladesh ", " Barbados ", " Belgium ", 
" Belgium ", " Belize ", " Belize ", " Bolivia ", " Bosnia and Herzegovina ", 
" Brazil ", " Brazil ", " Bulgaria ", " Bulgaria ", " Canada ", 
" Canada ", " Cape Verde    ", " Chile ", " Chile ", " China ", 
" China ", " Colombia ", " Colombia ", " Costa Rica ", " Croatia ", 
" Croatia ", " Cyprus ", " Czech Republic ", " Czech Republic ", 
" Denmark ", " Dominican Republic      ", " Dominican Republic ", 
" Dominican Republic ", " Ecuador ", " Egypt ", " Egypt ", " El Salvador ", 
" El Salvador ", " El Salvador      ", " Estonia    ", " Ethiopia ", 
" Finland ", " Finland ", " France ", " France ", " France ", 
" Germany ", " Germany      ", " Germany ", " Greece ", " Greece ", 
" Greece ", " Grenada ", " Guatemala      ", " Guatemala ", " Haiti ", 
" Haiti ", " Honduras ", " Honduras ", " Hungary ", " Hungary ", 
" Iceland ", " India    ", " Indonesia ", " Indonesia ", " Iraq      ", 
" Ireland ", " Ireland ", " Israel ", " Israel ", " Israel ", 
" Italy ", " Italy ", " Italy ", " Jamaica ", " Japan      ", 
" Japan ", " Japan      ", " Jordan ", " Kenya ", " Kuwait      ", 
" Latvia ", " Lebanon ", " Liberia ", " Liechtenstein    ", " Lithuania ", 
" Luxembourg      ", " Macedonia ", " Malaysia ", " Malta ", 
" Mauritius ", " Mexico ", " Mexico ", " Mexico ", " Monaco ", 
" Mongolia ", " Morocco ", " Nepal ", " Netherlands ", " New Zealand    ", 
" Nicaragua ", " Norway ", " Pakistan ", " Pakistan ", " Paraguay ", 
" Peru ", " Peru ", " Peru ", " Philippines ", " Philippines ", 
" Poland ", " Poland ", " Portugal ", " Portugal ", " Republic of Korea ", 
" Republic of Korea ", " Romania ", " Romania ", " Rwanda ", 
" Saint Kitts and Nevis    ", " Sao Tome and Principe ", " Saudi Arabia ", 
" Serbia ", " Singapore ", " Slovakia ", " Slovakia ", " South Africa ", 
" South Africa ", " Spain ", " Spain ", " Spain ", " Sri Lanka      ", 
" Sri Lanka ", " Sweden ", " Switzerland ", " Tanzania ", " Thailand    ", 
" Thailand ", " Turkey ", " Turkey ", " Turkey ", " United Arab Emirates ", 
" Uganda ", " Ukraine    ", " United Arab Emirates ", " United Kingdom ", 
" United Kingdom ", " Uruguay ", " Venezuela ", " Venezuela ", 
City = c("Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Boston", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Boston", "Los Angeles", 
"Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Boston", 
"Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Boston", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Boston", 
"Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Boston", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Los Angeles", "Boston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Crystal Lake", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Boston", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Boston"),
```

Comment: I think you should try using `%in%`

Comment: If I had a reproducible example I could quickly check it out, but I think something like this would work: `Embassy$name %in% c(Embassy$city[, c('Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Boston'), ])`

Comment: The %in% example I tried but it returned the following: logical(0)

Comment: Nvm the above, see the answer @tyluRp.

Answer (score 1):

```
#install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)

Embassy_Name <- c("Argentina",           
              "Argentina",           
              "Belgium",             
              "Bulgaria",           
              "Switzerland",         
              "Switzerland",         
              "Switzerland"  )

City_name <- c("Chicago",    
           "Boston",    
           "LA",  
           "LA",   
           "Boston",   
           "LA",      
           "Chicago")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Embassy_Name,City_name))

df_2 <- sqldf('SELECT Embassy_Name,
          COUNT(City_name) AS COUNT
  FROM df
  GROUP BY Embassy_Name
  HAVING COUNT > 2'
  )

list <- as.character(unique(df_2$Embassy_Name))

print(list)
```

Comment: My dataframe has 156 observations for Embassy_name so how does this code work when using it from the imported csv rather than creating the vector c("Boston" etc... because I don't want to have to type out every city name 156 times and then again for embassy name?

Comment: if you import a csv into a data frame and then use the code starting at df_2 <-..., that should work.

Comment: He did that to re-create your example.. :) That's why it'd be better in the future to provide a copy-paste code yourself.

Comment: the code provided still doesn't work with my data  this is my error:  
Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(rs@ptr, value) : 
  Parameter 2 does not have length 312.

Comment: Error handling with sqldf is not great.  Are you using the correct variable names?  I know sqldf will throw a cryptic error if you have more than one column in the same df with the same name.

Comment: try this dplyr equivalent:                                                                   `df_2 <- df %>%group_by(Embassy_Name) %>%
mutate(COUNT = n_distinct(City_name)) %>%
filter(COUNT>2)`

Comment: Yep those are the variable names in my csv, it still won't work

Comment: FOR THE DPLYR: same with errors reading the following: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Embassy$embassy` must be length 156 (the number of rows) or one, not 312